# ASP/VB: Counting and ordering array values

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

I am new to writing in asp and vb and am stuck on a piece of logic where I need to retrieve data from a web form, count the number of entries and then order them alphanumerically.

I have a webform with the multiple text boxes that can be filled out and submitted that looks a little like this: (excuse the spreadsheet, it's a visual aid only)

[image]

I have made an array that contains their values like this:

```
myArray = array(town, medal, record, sport)
```

**I would like to count and order (everything alphanumerically) the total medals, how many of each medal each town won and the number of records set by each town.**

My psuedocode looks a little like this, hopefully I am a little on the right track in terms of logic. The main area I am a little short in is knowing what statements would be good and where, especially to order them alphanumerically.

```
'this is the psuedocode for the total medals per town
tally = 0 'Set tally to 0
for myArray(town) 'For each town
    for myArray(medal) 'For each medal
        tally = tally + 1 'Add 1 to the total tally
        response.write(myArray(town) "has" tally "medals" & "<br>")
    next
next

'this is the pseudocode for the individual medals
for myArray(town) 'For each town
    for myArray(medal) 'For each medal
        goldTally = 0
        silverTally = 0
        bronzeTally = 0
        if medal = "G"
            goldTally = goldTally + 1
        elseif medal = "S"
            silverTally = silverTally + 1
        else medal = "B"
            bronzeTally = bronzeTally + 1
        response.write(myArray(town) "has:" goldTally "gold medals" &"<br>"
                                         silverTally "silver medals" &"<br>"
                                         bronzeTally "bronze medals" &"<br>" 
    next
next
```

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated thanks heaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VBScript tool for counting/grouping/classifying is the [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). Some use cases: [Set ops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6592801/603855), [word list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34717613/603855), [split file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12255167/603855).

Simple Arrays can be sorted via using an [ArrayList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). [Array vs Arraylist], [fancy sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13758037/603855)[7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023724/assign-a-new-value-to-an-existing-item-in-an-array-vbs).

For tabular data, use a disconnected [recordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms681510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Inline demo:

```
Option Explicit

' simple sample data
Dim a : a = Split("b c a b b c a a b")

' use a dictionary for counting/grouping
Dim d : Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim e
For Each e In a
    d(e) = d(e) + 1
Next
WScript.Echo Join(d.Keys)
WScript.Echo Join(d.Items)

' use an ArrayList for sorting simple arrays
Dim l : Set l = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
For Each e in a
    l.Add e
Next
l.Sort
WScript.Echo Join(l.ToArray())

' use a disconnected recordset for tabular data
Const adVarChar    = 200
Const adInteger    = 2
Const adClipString = 2
Dim r : Set r = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
r.Fields.Append "k", adVarChar, 50
r.Fields.Append "n", adInteger
r.Open
For Each e In d.Keys
    r.AddNew
    r.Fields("k").value = e
    r.Fields("n").value = d(e)
    r.Update
Next
r.MoveFirst
Do Until r.EOF
   WScript.Echo r.Fields("k").value, r.Fields("n").value
   r.MoveNext
Loop
r.Sort = "k DESC"
WScript.Echo r.GetString(adClipString, , ", ", "; ", "null")
```

output:

```
cscript 39305170.vbs
b c a
4 2 3
a a a b b b b c c
a 3
c, 2; b, 4; a, 3;
```

BTW: Even in a pseudo code language,

```
for myArray(town) 'For each town
```

and

```
response.write(myArray(town) "has:" goldTally "gold medals" ...
```

can't work at the same time.